# Windows Phone 8.1 Email + Accounts

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, user-accounts

I am working on windows phone 8.1 application which creates a contact store and adds/deletes contacts.

Is there a way that i can get my app name under email + accounts in settings ? Would it be possible do to this in Windows phone 8.1(RT) ?

Comment: You want to programmatically retrieve your own application name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want you app act as a contacts provider, appearing in the Emails + accounts section of Settings. This is no currently possible.